# input and search form issue

Tags: php, html

```
 <form name="search" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
 Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
 <Select NAME="field">
 <Option VALUE="english">english</option>
 <Option VALUE="spanish">spanish</option>
 </Select>
 <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
 </form>

  <?php
$options = array('english'=> array('1' => 'one', '2' => 'two'), 'spanish' =>array('1'=>'uno', '2'=>'dos'));

if (($_POST['find'] == '1')&& ($_POST['field'] == 'english')){
    echo $options['english']['1'];
}
?>
```

I want to have this function, when user input '1' and seclet 'english', it will show one, when user input '1' sellect 'spanish', it will show uno, and so on.

Questions:

1. Is there any good way to replace this line?

> ```
>  if (($_POST['find'] == '1')&& ($_POST['field'] == 'english')){
>       echo $options['english']['1'];
>     }
> ```

imagine if i have number from 1 to 100, it is impossible for me to repete these codes(==1 && ==english, ==2 && == english...).

2 if u run this script, it shows

> Notice: Undefined index: find ...

what is this probem and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you consider this: http://code.google.com/p/google-translate-php-wrapper/ - I am not aware of the details though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First point :*

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

The `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` will do nothing. You shall have to use **echo** here. Nevertheless, the bug does not show because it's the default behaviour for a form to call the script at $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] when the action attribute is not set.

Also :

```
<input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
```

seems useless.

*Second point :*

Of course you don't want to parse each possible choice in a static fashion. You'll use abstraction and dynamic behavior.

You have one array index by language and each sub array gives the word used for each number. Hence, you have your rule and your computations will look like :

```
<?php
$input = trim($_POST['find']);
$language = $_POST['field'];
$output = $options[$language][$input];
echo $output;
?>
```

That's minimal code. Please don't use it 'as is'. You'll have at least to check if keys exist and provide some adequate error messages.

Comment: Never even name `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` without placing a big fat security implications warning sign. The OP obviously took over crap code from even more crappier PHP examples.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like even on initial page load you're checking for posted values. Try wrapping the bottom php code like this:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        $options = array('english'=> array('1' => 'one', '2' => 'two'), 'spanish' =>array('1'=>'uno', '2'=>'dos'));

        if (($_POST['find'] == '1')&& ($_POST['field'] == 'english')){
            echo $options['english']['1'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$html =<<<'HTML'

<form name="search" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
 Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
 <Select NAME="field">
 <Option VALUE="english">english</option>
 <Option VALUE="spanish">spanish</option>
 </Select>
 <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
 </form>
HTML;

echo $html;

$options = array('english'=> array('1' => 'one', '2' => 'two'), 'spanish' =>array('1'=>'uno', '2'=>'dos'));

if ((isset($_POST['find']) == '1')&& (isset($_POST['field']) == 'english')){
    echo $options['english']['1'];
}
?>
```